# How to deploy war file tomcat running on amazon ec2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, tomcat6, cloud-hosting

I have install tomcat 6.0 and mysql 5.5 on amazon linux instance.
now i want to deploy war file on that tomcate & .sql file on mysql running on amazon instance .I am new for amazon services.Plz give details about procedure.
Plz help me for that .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is use scp or rsync to upload file and restart Tomcat. 
However if you have many servers or WARs, even more complicated situation, consider other ways:

1. use jenkins to deploy
2. write your deploy script leveraged by python-fabric

You should design your own deploy process to overcome the difficulties you met.
In my case is every ec2 instances are spot instance, they are created by scripts or autoscaling.
We should keep the every new spot instance update to date, using the latest software and JARs to run web crawler. 
Our design is very simple. Just a script to download files from S3 and unzip it:

1. ec2 spot instance completed booting
2. run the software-update script
3. run the software script getting from the updater

In your case, there are some key point you not figure out:

1. How many ec2 instance should update ?
2. A ec2 instance how to know it need to update.
3. (many other points)

What is the best way to deploy your WARs ? It depends on your situation.